# Hi , I need a regex to match everything and convert to upper case except the text that are inside the single quotes in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Assuming I have a sentence like:

```
anything but 'notthis' and also 'not this' and 'notthis'
```

I would like my output be:

```
ANYTHING BUT 'notthis' AND ALSO 'not this' AND 'notthis'
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You will have more success with help once you have had a go with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following substitution should hopefully work for you:

```
s/((?:'[^']*')*)([^']+)/$1\U$2/g;
```

Parentheses form marching groups; the first left parenthesis creates a back reference called `$1`, the next one is `$2`, etc. To avoid creating groups, the form `(:?` is a parenthesis which does not create a back reference.

The first group captures and skips phrases in single quotes; they are substituted back as themselves in `$1`. The group can match an empty string.

The second group captures a string which does not contain single quotes. Because the `+` repetition operator is greedy, it will match up to just before the next single quote, or end of string. It is converted to uppercase by `\U` in the substitution.

The `/g` flag repeats as many times as possible, starting over where the previous match ended.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $string = "your string 'no upper case' sample";

my @arr = split/('.*?')/,$string;

foreach my $data(@arr)
{
    if($data !~ /'/)
    {
        $data = uc $data;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}


$string = join '',@arr;

print "$string";
```